# Group points by expression to create pie charts in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, symbology, expression, chart

Is the any way to group multiple points by attribute to make pie charts that shows types by locations?

I have a layer with groups of points with two fields (group and type). Every group of points is exactly in the same location.

What I want to do is to show a pie char in every location showing as many parts as types is in the group.

I've been trying out with `count` as @Kazuhito suggested in the expression constructor of the diagrams creator of the layer, but the charts are blank.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With a simple test data of 2 locations ("group" in this case) with 6 points each;

[image]

Create a new field to count each type at each location, for instance `type_A` by:

```
count( "type", group_by:= "group", filter:= "type"='A')
```

Here `group_by:=` part defines the group to aggregate, while the `filter:=` extracts the data matching with the condition `"type"='A'`.

Repeat this to create new fields according to your types.

[image]

When you create the pie chart, you may have to choose `Over point` as the Placement option.

[image]

Comment: It works perfect, but what I'm trying to avoid is creating new fields.

I've tried to use your sugestion in the expression builder when settings the atributes for the pie chart but it not work there...

![expression builder](https://i.imgur.com/YlulX8l.png)

Comment: @Viskovitz you may use virtual field, this way you are not permanently creating new field in your layer (they will show only in this specific project) or you could create a virtual layer just for the creation of the pie chart. but yes it would be nice to see a simpler solution using only the diagrams dialog

Comment: Finally I did what @J.R proposed and it worked fine. Thanks.